# blkid encrypted partition to get UUID

Tags: encryption, uuid

Partition is created with: cryptsetup -y create tmp1 /dev/sdc3

sudo blkid /dev/sdc3 gives nothing and partition sdc3 cannot be mounted.

Am i rigth that partition created with cryptsetup create cannot have UUID before it is mounted in unencrypted state by "cryptsetup open".

Do i need to create partition as LUKS by c

Answer (score 0):

Just looks like you have your commands a little out of order. You seem to have a partition already so, to make a LUKS container you should use: cryptsetup {options} luksFormat /dev/'device'

Then: cryptsetup {options} luksOpen /dev/'device' 'label'

---

ArchLinux has an extremely detailed HowTo to help get you started: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt_with_LUKS

Most distro's will have a howto somewhere as well.